# How to find mutated object while being enumerated in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Hi one of my application is crashsing with below error is there any way to find at which object it's actually crashing using instruments.

Crash Message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0xc3521c0> was mutated while being enumer

Please help me thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Actually the error is probably correct. Is there code looping over a dictionary and changing it? Add some code to the question!

Answer (score 0):

Set an exception breakpoint and the debugger will stop when the exception is thrown. That should make the offending object pretty clear.

Take a close look at the error message: it's *telling* you what object threw the exception. It's a dictionary at `0xc3521c0`, and the problem is that you're somehow changing it while you're iterating over it. That is, you can't do something like this:

```
for (id foo in someDictionary) {
    //...
    someDictionary[someKey] = someObject; // error -- don't change the array that you're looping on
    //...
}
```

Comment: That will stop on the line but to see the cause hit continue (control-command-Y) twice and you will the reason and stack trace and possible a helpful hint.

Comment: Hi Caleb and Zaph thanks for your help. I added All Exceptions break point my app crashes with this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0xb410fa0> was mutated while being enumerated.' but it did not show any object.:( For your reference i am attching the screenshot to my question.

Comment: The breakpoint should stop on the line with the error. Add the code at and around that point to your question (you can edit your own question). With no code there isn't going to be much or any help.